# How to read each row in a groovy-sql statement?

Tags: sql, groovy, groovy-sql

I am trying to read a table having five rows and columns. I have used sql.eachRow function to read eachRow and assign the value to a String. I am getting an error "Groovy:[Static type checking] - No such property: MachineName for class: java.lang.Object"

My code:

```
sql.eachRow('select * from [MACHINES] WHERE UpdateTime > :lastTimeRead, [lastTimeRead: Long.parseLong(lastTimeRead)])
{ row ->
    def read = row.MachineName
}
```

but MachineName is my column name. How can i overcome this error.

Comment: Have you tried without static type checking/compile?

Comment: Have you tried column name with lower case like `row.machinename`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using dynamic Properties with static type checking is not possible*.

However, [`eachRow`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/sql/GroovyResultSet.html) will pass a [`GroovyResultSet`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/sql/GroovyResultSet.html) as first parameter to the `Closure`. This means that `row` has the type `GroovyResultSet` and so you can access the value using [`getAt`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/sql/GroovyResultSet.html#getAt-java.lang.String-)

```
row.getAt('MachineName')
```

should work. In groovy you can also use the `[]`-operator:

```
row['MachineName']
```

which is equivalent to the first solution.

*) without a [type checking extension](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/next/html/documentation/type-checking-extensions.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you Know the Column name you can just use the Below.

```
"$row.MachineName"
```

But if you don't Know column name or having some issue, still it can be accessed using an array of Select.

```
sql.eachRow('select * from [MACHINES] WHERE UpdateTime > :lastTimeRead, [lastTimeRead: Long.parseLong(lastTimeRead)]) 
{ row->
        log.info "First value = ${row[0]}, next value = ${row[1]}"
}
```